# Text does not align left inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some `span` element inside a `div` to it's left border.
This is currently my code:

```css
.bikoret
{
    width:40%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.bikoret > .content
{
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bikoret > .username
{
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    border-top:1px inset;
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl" style="text-align:center; background-color:White; border-top:1px; border-style:inset; margin-top:4px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" runat="server" id="takzir">
    <center>
        <div class='bikoret'>
            <div class='content'>
                this is centered
            </div>
            <span class='username'>this is aligned to left</span>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

How can I fix it? I tried everything by now..

Comment: Try fixing your phrase first. "Centred to the left" is way to contradictory :)

Comment: The centered part should stay the same. The line under the centered part element should go to the left. @nicael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this.

First, I define a class for the parent block, `.parent`, with your current styling and add `text-align: center`.

For the child element `.bikoret`, apply `display: inline-block` which means that
this element is centered within the parent.  Important: set `text-align: left`.

For the child elements of `.bikoret`, treat each element separately.

For `.content`, I would set the width to `auto` and `text-align: center` to center your text.

For `.username`, this is simply an inline element, and because of `text-align: left` on its parent (`.bikoret`) it sits to the left edge as you want.

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: White;
  border-top: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.bikoret {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.bikoret > .content {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto; /* Why 80%? */
  padding: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bikoret > .username {
  padding-left: 1em; /* % padding won't really work here... */
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-top: 1px inset;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class='bikoret'>
    <div class='content'>this is centered</div>
    <span class='username'>this is aligned to left</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The `center` tag is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

adding a `display: block;` to your class `.username` will do the job, but here's another ways of doing it

**==========**

By giving a `position: relative;` to your container `.bikoret` along with a height to avoid the border not being covering the `.username` and a position absolute to `.username` as well, will do it:

```
.bikoret {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.bikoret > .username {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px inset;
}
```

Here's an **[online example](http://jsfiddle.net/sggoL136/)**

**======== Or if this is all about the divider ========**

You can do something like this

```
<div class='bikoret'>
    <div class='content'>this is centered</div>
        <div class='divider'></div>
    <span class='username'>this is aligned to left</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bikoret {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.divider {
    height: 1px;
    background: #909090;
    width: 60%;
}
.bikoret > .username {
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
}
```

**Here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sggoL136/2/)**

Comment: I want the width of `username` to stay the same. I just want to move it to the left without sizing the div and `text-align:left;`

Comment: I can't rely on a static height, because the content of the div may change and I need it to be related to the content.

Answer (score 1):

To center a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements): set `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to itself.

To center an [inline level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente): set `text-align:center;` to its parent.

**Updated working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/k2xh3xya/1/

HTML

```
<div dir="rtl" style="" runat="server" id="takzir">
    <center>
        <div class='bikoret'>
            <div class='content'>this is centered</div>
            <span class='username'>this is aligned to left</span>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#takzir {
    background-color:White;
    border-top:1px;
    border-style:inset;
    margin-top:4px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.bikoret {
    width:40%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}
.bikoret > .content {
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
}
.bikoret > .username {
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
    border-top:1px inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the "this is aligned to left" to be moved all the way to the left? If so then you could simplify your HTML and CSS.

```css
.textOuter {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  border-top:1px;
  border-style:inset;
  margin-top:4px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.textInner {
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  left:30%;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.textCenter {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

hr {
  width:80%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  left:10%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.textFull {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="textOuter">
  <div class="textInner">
    <div class="textCenter">this is centered</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="textFull">this is aligned to left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```